# Handling CSR data file

Tags: python, numpy, sparse-matrix

I have sparse matrix data stored in npy format. I am reading the file and storing it in CSR format. And the below code works perfectly:

```
def load_adjacency_matrix_csr(folder: str,
                              filename: str,
                              suffix: str = "npy",
                              row_idx: int = 1,
                              num_rows: int = None,
                              dtype: np.dtype = np.float32) -> sparse.csr_matrix:
    coo_indices = np.load(os.path.join(folder, f"{filename}.{suffix}"))
    rows = coo_indices[row_idx]
    cols = coo_indices[1 - row_idx]
    data = np.ones(len(rows), dtype=dtype)

    num_rows = num_rows or rows.max() + 1
    if num_rows < rows.max() + 1:
        raise ValueError("The number of rows in the file is larger than the specified number of rows.")
    csr_mat = sparse.csr_matrix((data, (rows, cols)), shape=(num_rows, num_rows), dtype=dtype)
    return csr_mat
```

Now I read the same file, write it to a new file (_temp) and then I read. But now when I read from this new file (_temp), I get an error `Detected 1 oom-kill even(s)`. This out of memory happens when creating the CSR matrix. But this is the exact same number of rows/columns and data as when I was able to successfully execute when I directly from the file. I am unable to figure out what changed when writing to a new file (the rows/columns and data has not changed).

```
def save_coo_matrix(npx: int,
                    folder: str,
                    filename: str,
                    suffix: str = "npy",
                    row_idx: int = 1,
                    dtype: np.dtype = np.float32) -> None:

  file_path = os.path.join(folder, f"{filename}.{suffix}")
  coo_indices = np.load(file_path)
  rows = coo_indices[row_idx]
  cols = coo_indices[1 - row_idx]
  filename += "_temp"
  file_path = os.path.join(folder, f"{filename}.npz")
  np.savez(file_path, rows=rows, cols=cols)
```

```
def load_adjacency_matrix_csr(npx: int,
                              folder: str,
                              filename: str,
                              suffix: str = "npy",
                              row_idx: int = 1,
                              num_rows: int = None,
                              dtype: np.dtype = np.float32) -> sparse.csr_matrix:
    file_path = os.path.join(folder, f"{filename}_padded.npz")
    with np.load(file_path) as data:
        rows = data["rows"]
        cols = data["cols"]
        num_rows = max(rows) + 1
        num_cols = max(cols) + 1
        values = np.ones(len(rows))
        # fails here when creating the csr matrix (the num_rows is the same value as before)
        csr_mat = sparse.csr_matrix((values, (rows, cols)), shape=(num_rows, num_cols))

    return csr_mat
```

Comment: `sparse` has a `save/load` pair that use the `savez` like you do.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be a mismatch in the file extensions you use when writing and reading the data. when you call `load_adjacency_matrix_csr`, make sure to set the suffix parameter to `csr_matrix = load_adjacency_matrix_csr(npx, folder, filename, suffix="npz", ...)` also the npx is not used within the function. You can remove this parameter from the function definition.